# React native reload bundle programmatically

Tags: android, react-native, react-android, metro-bundler

I want to develop a react native app. But js files aren't on my local machine. I will download bundle from remote server.

Below code works for now. But how can I reload js bundle from file path?

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    public static String mBundleFilePath = "sdcard/Download/index.android.bundle";

    public final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage()
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index";
        }
        @Override
        protected String getJSBundleFile() {
            return mBundleFilePath;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    }
}
```

There are some methods for reloading. But it doesn't support external path.
[reloadJSFromServer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1151c096dab17e5d9a6ac05b61aacecd4305f3db/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/devsupport/DisabledDevSupportManager.java)  works for only http/https.

```
getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getDevSupportManager().reloadJSFromServer(httpUrl);
```

handleReloadJS loads from localhost/8081

```
getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getDevSupportManager().handleReloadJS();
```

**EDIT**

Restart activity doesn't work for me :)

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
finish();
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
ReactInstanceManager manager = application.getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager();

manager.recreateReactContextInBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use library https://github.com/avishayil/react-native-restart.

```js
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'; // Import package from node modules

// Immediately reload the React Native Bundle
RNRestart.restart();
```